# How to Render Mutliple tr Rows in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stuck with this, when i am running the code is get this error.

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0):
> Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly
> mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody>
> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using
> non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of
> the element with React ID ``.
> ```

Please help me to solve this.

```
var TicketsList = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                var TicketNodes = this.props.data.map(function (ticket){
                    return(
                        <tr>
                            <td className="txt-c">
                                <span className="pr-5 f-18" title="Responses">
                                    <span>{ticket.responses}</span>
                                    <i className="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 
                                </span>
                                <span className="pr-5 f-18" title="Attachments">
                                    <span>{ticket.attachments}</span>
                                    <i className="fa fa-paperclip"></i> 
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>{ticket.message}</td>
                            <td>{ticket.recorded_support_type}</td>
                            <td>{ticket.recorded_sub_type}</td>
                            <td>{ticket.recorded_priority}</td>
                            <td>{ticket.recorded_status}</td>
                            <td>{ticket.submitted_by_name}</td>
                            <td>{ticket.assigned_to}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                });
                return (
                    <tbody>
                        {TicketNodes}
                    </tbody>
                );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wrapping that contents with a `<table>` somewhere else? A `<tbody>` element should always be wrapped in a `<table>` element.

Comment: Got it, found my error fixed it. Thanks for helping

Comment: Please do explain what the error was and how you fixed it.

Comment: here  i am returning  `<tbody>`. In my  render method a  i gave the reference of `React.render(
        <Tickets url="ticket_detail" />,
        document.getElementById('tickets')
    );` the tickets id is tbody. when i changed the reference to other table tag its working

Comment: So the problem was that you didn't have a `<table>` element?